# LEd (LaTeX Editor) lagging while typing commands

Tags: editors, performance, led-editor

Hello I am using LEd editor. It is my favorite editor and I would like to keep using it. But for some time it is unusable because it laggs so much when I start typing commands. Whenever I type '\' and then start to write it lags a ton. I think it is caused by syntax hints.

It has started since I downloaded MixTex2.9 (I used 2.7 before) and I do not really know why it is happening. Does anyone know if some configuration changes can be made to improve performance of editor? I would like to stay with LEd and preserve syntax hints.

If it is not possible could you recommend any LaTeX editor which has nice toolbar above editor textbox and has customable hotkeys for commonly used code like `alt+shift+num` in LEd?

Thank you and best regards,

Maks

Comment: On the site I see the program has not been updated since 2009. You can look at TeXStudio.

Comment: It is stated on the homepage that they add support for [MikTex 2.8](http://latexeditor.org/news.html#2008-04-15). I interpret that as MikTeX 2.9 is not supported.

Comment: That may be the case. Thanks for pointing that out!